# Syntax error I cannot figure out. Getting an error on my table column name

Tags: java, android-studio

I am getting the following syntax error:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "dairy": syntax error
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: apps.fsc.foodtrackertuesday, PID: 17718
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{apps.fsc.foodtrackertuesday/apps.fsc.foodtrackertuesday.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "dairy": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE products(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, fruit VARCHAR(255) dairyError VARCHAR(255) grains VARCHAR(255) vegetables VARCHAR(255) protein VARCHAR(255) );

```
public class myDBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
// Define some global database stuff

private static final int        DATABASE_VERSION    = 1;
private static final String     DATABASE_NAME       = "database";

// Define a table and some columns
private static final String     TABLE_NAME                  = "products";
private static final String     COLUMN_ID                   = "_id";
private static final String     COLUMN_PRODUCT_FRUIT        = "fruit";
private static final String     COLUMN_PRODUCT_DAIRY        = "dairy";
private static final String     COLUMN_PRODUCT_GRAINS       = "grains";
private static final String     COLUMN_PRODUCT_VEGETABLES   = "vegetables";
private static final String     COLUMN_PRODUCT_PROTEIN      = "protein";
```

Comment: You need commas between your column declarations.

Comment: @mypetlion Where exactly?

Comment: When I tried Android Studio did not like it.

Comment: After the type, before the next item in the list. `CREATE TABLE products(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, fruit VARCHAR(255), dairyError VARCHAR(255), grains VARCHAR(255), vegetables VARCHAR(255), protein VARCHAR(255) );`